# Не получается передать bundle из одного фрагмента в другой

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, textview, bundles

Из одного фрагмента передаю данные в другой фрагмент. Код откуда:

```
Text text;

myFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

text = new Text();
final FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = myFragmentManager
        .beginTransaction();

btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("javaText", R.string.btn1javaA1);
        text.setArguments(bundle);
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, text).commit();
    }
});
```

Код куда:

```
TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);

Bundle bundle = getArguments();
if (bundle != null) {
    String javaText = bundle.getString("javaText");
    text.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    text.setText(Html.fromHtml(javaText));
}
```

Но приложение вылетает. Мне нужно передать текст с одного фрагмента в другой в зависимости от того куда нажал пользователь.

Comment: Во-первых никогда не называйте фрагмент `text`, если уж такой нейминг - то `textFragment` и тип `TextFragment`
Во-вторых - не держите транзакцию в виде поля. Вот вы хотите сделать транзакцию внутри метода `onClick` там её и создавайте.
В-третьих - прикрепите стектрейс ошибки

Comment: спасибо за советы

Comment: Возможно такое решение Вам тоже подойдет. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1398630/397512

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых никогда не называйте фрагмент `text`, если уж такой нейминг - то `textFragment` и тип `TextFragment`

Во-вторых - не держите транзакцию в виде поля. Вот вы хотите сделать транзакцию внутри метода `onClick` там её и создавайте.

В-третьих - прикрепите стектрейс ошибки

По ошибке - вы в бандл суёте `Integer` и хотите достать `String` конечно у вас падает приложение.
Закидывайте в `bundle` строку `getString(R.string.btn1javaA1)` 
А вообще - вы эту строку держите в ресурсах. Зачем её кидать в бандл, eсли второй фрагмент её может спокойно достать из ресурсов

Comment: getInt не заметил. Мне нужно узнать что пользователь нажал в одном фрагменте и в зависимости от этого достать нужный текст из ресурсов. И чтобы не делать для этого каждый фрагмент, я сделал один - "text"

Comment: иначе как еще передать?

Comment: все заработало, но вместо текста цифры почему-то

Comment: вы сделали getInt? Этот Int - это айди вашего ресурса. а не сама строка.