# Не могу передать ArrayList из одного фрагмента в другой (wrong argument type)

Tags: java, android, android-bundle

Встретился с проблемой, не могу представить, в чем дело.
Есть 2 фрагмента - A и B. Из первого фрагмента мне необходимо передать во второй фрагмент массив data типа ArrayList.

Передаю данные и перехожу с помощью navigate из NavController в методе action(). Программа собирается без ошибок, но при нажатии на кнопку, к которой привязан метод action, происходит вылет, ошибка следующая:

*java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong argument type for 'array' in argument bundle. java.util.ArrayList expected.*

То есть написано, что я передаю аргумент неверного типа, нужен ArrayList. Но я и передаю ему ArrayList, что не так то?

Помогите, пожалуйста, укажите что не так, второй день голову ломаю.

Код фрагмента А:

```
package com.github.dev.app.pack;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment;
import com.github.vladosspasi.mes.databinding.FragmentABinding;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

    private FragmentABinding binding;
    private ArrayList<Integer> data; // массив, который хочу передать

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState
    ) {
        binding = FragmentAsBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        return binding.getRoot();
    }


    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        data = new ArrayList<>(); //инициализирую
        data.add(1);              //чем-то заполняю

        binding.actionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                action();   //метод, в котором должны осуществляться передача и переход
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }

    private void action() {

        Bundle arg = new Bundle();
        arg.putSerializable("array", data); //putIntegerArrayList так же не работает

        NavHostFragment.findNavController(FragmentA.this)
             .navigate(R.id.action_FragmentA_to_FragmentB, arg); //строка, в которой обнаружена ошибка

    }
}
```

Код фрагмента B не прилагаю, до него исполнение не доходит.

Объявление фрагментов в nav_graph.xml:

```
    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/FragmentA"
            android:name="com.github.dev.app.pack.FragmentA"
            android:label="Fragment A">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_FragmentA_to_FragmentB"
            app:destination="@id/FragmentB"/>
    </fragment>

    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/FragmentB"
            android:name="com.github.dev.app.pack.FragmentB"
            android:label="Fragment B">
        <argument android:name="array" app:argType="java.util.ArrayList"/>
    </fragment>
```

С аргументами типа int, String и т.п. все окей, но массивы ну никак не хотят передаваться. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Сработал данный метод передачи:

 bundle.putParcelableArrayList("array",data);

Но для его реализации понадобилось создать новый класс с наследованием от Parcelable, который хранит всего 1 число. В метод я передаю массив элементов как раз этого класса.
По-моему это выглядит немного громоздко и не очень правильно. Может кто-нибудь, пожалуйста, объяснить, почему это работает именно так? Есть ли другие пути решения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сработал следующий способ:

```
bundle.putParcelableArrayList("array",data)
```

Для использования требуется объявить data следующим образом:

```
ArrayList<ParInteger> data;
```

где ParInteger - новый класс, который требуется создать. Внутри него всего одно поле, хранящее int. Класс должен реализовывать интерфейс Parcelable (все Override методы, требуемые Parcelable, для моих целей можно оставить без реализации).
Может не самое элегантное решение, но меня оно устраивает.

Благодарю всех за ответы и помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Может и не актуально, но для получения данных из активности, просто назначаем метод в фрагменте, а для передачи данных из фрагмента в активность, реализуем интерфейс в активности, интерфейс ожидает наш фрагмент, вот пример простого кода

```
public class BlankFragmentA extends Fragment {

    // Фрагменты не могут напрямую взаимодействовать между собой.
    // Для этого надо обращаться к контексту, в качестве которого
    // выступает класс Activity. Для обращения к activity, как правило,
    // создается вложенный интерфейс
    public interface OnFragmentSendDataListener {
        void onSendData(String dataSend, int number);
    }

    public void getSendData(String dataReceive) {
        ((TextView) this.view.findViewById(R.id.txvReceiveText)).setText(dataReceive);
    }

    // ссылка на активность, в которой находится фрагмент
    private OnFragmentSendDataListener activivtyRetranslator;

    // при подключении к активности, context -  ссылка на активнсоть
    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        try {
            activivtyRetranslator = (OnFragmentSendDataListener) context;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(context
                    + " должен реализовывать интерфейс OnFragmentSendDataListener");
        } // try-catch
    } // onAttach

    public BlankFragmentA() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    View view;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        this.view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank_a, container, false);

        // получаем элемент ListView
        this.view.findViewById(R.id.btnSendText).setOnClickListener((v) -> {
            switch (this.view.getId()) {
                case R.id.frA:
                    // Посылаем данные в Activity для ретрансляции в Fragment
                    activivtyRetranslator.onSendData("Hello from Fragment A", 2);
                    break;
                case R.id.frB:
                    // Посылаем данные в Activity для ретрансляции в Fragment
                    activivtyRetranslator.onSendData("Hello from Fragment B", 1);
                    break;
            }
        });

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return view;
    }
}
```

Разметка

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".BlankFragmentA">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txvReceiveText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSendText"
        android:text="Send"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

И соответственно активность использующая данный фрагмент

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BlankFragmentA.OnFragmentSendDataListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSendData(String dataSend, int number) {
        switch(number)
        {
            case 1:
                // получаем ссылку на фрагмент-приемник
                BlankFragmentA fragment = (BlankFragmentA) getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.frA);
                fragment.getSendData(dataSend);
                break;
            case 2:
                // получаем ссылку на фрагмент-приемник
                fragment = (BlankFragmentA) getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.frB);
                fragment.getSendData(dataSend);
                break;

        }
    }
}
```

И разметка активности:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/frA"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:name="com.example.myapplicationtestfragment.BlankFragmentA"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/frB"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:name="com.example.myapplicationtestfragment.BlankFragmentA"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Я пробовал делать так до использования bundle, но по какой то причине он не работал, хотя я делал все так же и не раз перепроверял. Но все равно спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Создайте отдельно класс Global и добавьте туда:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> data = new ArrayList<>();
```

И обращайтесь к нему с любого фрагмента(активности):

```
Global.data.add(0); // добавляем элемент

int num = Global.data.get(0); // забираем элемент
```

Comment: Не лучшее решение давать всем доступ к данным, лучше инкапсулировать функциональность(данные) во фрагменте и делиться по мере надобности.